# Avoid time lap between two video

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

Rewrited since voted as on hold

My goal is to play video files following each other without transition.
Since I m working on a Raspberry Pi, it seems I m forced to stuck on omxplayer to play video files.

I m writing it in node.js because asynchronous programming is useful for other non-related part of the app.

My problem is, between each video, there is a short time where the screen display the  console before playing the next video. I m searching for any way to make the transition seemlessly.

For those who would want to reproduce this, here the code:

```
var Playlist=[],
    PIndice=0,
    PATH='';
    DOWNLOAD_DIR='';
    exec=require('child_process').exec,
    execF=require('child_process').execFile;

function start(){
    Playlist.push('video1.mp4');
    Playlist.push('video2.mp4');
    PATH=process.argv[1].substr(0, process.argv[1].indexOf('app.js', 0));
    DOWNLOAD_DIR=PATH+'downloads/';
    play(Playlist[0]);
}

function play(file){
    file=DOWNLOAD_DIR+file;
    execF(PATH+'play.sh', [file], function(error, stdout, stderr){
        if (err){throw err;}
        if (stdout){console.log(stdout);}
        if (stderr){console.log(stderr);}

        if(PIndice < Playlist.length -1){
            PIndice=PIndice+1;
        }else{
            PIndice=0;
        }
        play(Playlist[PIndice]);
    });
}

start();
```

You ll need this simple script too, in play.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
omxplayer $1 > /dev/null
```

And the app folder will look like:

```
folder/
    -app.js
    -play.sh
    -download/
        -video1.mp4
        -video2.mp4
```

And you launch the app by typing (in command line)

```
node app.js
```

omxplayer don t accept multiple files to play, so I do need to launch it each time.
If there s a player wich can play multiple file on RPi, I ll take it too.

EDIT:

After research, it strongly seem that there s no other video player for the raspberry pi (yeah, vlc, but it just eat all the gpu instead of playing anything, other player are just based on omxplayer), so I can t search for a solution here.

Is there any way to pre-load the video? Maybe tweaking play to start the following video some second before the one played end? Or do I need to rewrite omxplayer itself? Any thought are appreciated

EDIT 2:

Found a [old experimental edit of omxplayer with looping video](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/16), I m currently trying to compile it to test.

Comment: I think you should try editing your question to be more specific. The bottom line to speeding up node is to not block the event loop but it sounds like you just need to anticipate the video coming to an end so you can start loading the next.

Comment: In fact, my case is just to explain how I got this question, the goal is not to make SO debug my app, but to list all good habits to have for node.js, since I didn t saw any question like that. If I feel the need for help on my app, I ll ask for it in another question.

Comment: Edited the question to stick to where it end up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in a issue report in github a modified version of omxplayer which, at the cost of the last 6 mounth update and some severe requirement in the video files, give the possibility to play multiple file in a loop, without transition between each file.

It change a part of my algorithm, but at least I m back in the project requirement.

For thoses who could search for it: https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/16, check pasky comments, one of them have a link to the binary.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard to make general statements about the performance of an application without knowing too much about it, so I would suggest that you profile your application to see where the performance bottle necks are. Node has build in support for profiling. Just run with an additional option.

```
node --prof your_file.js
```

From the sound of it you might want to preload the next video sooner to avoid the pause the user is seeing

Comment: node --prof don t work, and don t appear in the option node --help, I have --eval and --print wich seems to be doing the same. I should have mentionned I m working on node v0.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Check [Flod](https://github.com/spumko/flod), tool for benchmarking Node.js web server

Comment: I know it can be weird to use node.js for that use, but I don t have any client request. The goal is to have a "Tv", the app download the video to play, and play them via omxplayer until the program is force-stopped. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the contents of the console to black by issuing a:

/usr/bin/tvservice -p

then your omxplayer stuff will just switch to black between movies.

Comment: The goal is to have no transition != black transition